# How do role-based authorization using identityserver4 for microservices architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, identityserver4, roles

**Prehistory:** 
I develop authentication and authorization for microservices using IdentityServer4, but have problem with authorization.
I have two services:
- service with identityserver4, it's my auth service
- test MVC project

I successfully connect these services and use Hybrid flow, and authentication work successfully, and also my roles works, because I include roles in JWT token using custom ProfileService on auth service side.

**Problem situation:**
1. User have not any auth token. Try open page with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute on MVC site and redirect to page on Auth service.
2. User enter login and password.
3. Got token with Role=Admin, redirect back to MVC site on Auth service.
4. Page opened for user, because he had Admin role.
5. Remove user from Admin role on Auth Service.
6. Reload page and page again opened fine for this user, and it's correct, because in token he had role admin.

**Question:** How I can actualize token after change roles or claims on auth service side?

**IdentityServer Config:**

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new Client[]
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "Epp.Web.Mvc",
                    ClientName = "Единый Портал Потребителей",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = new List<string>{GrantType.Hybrid},
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "epp",
                        "roles"
                    },
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
                        "https://localhost:5003/signin-oidc"
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>{ "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 60 * 10 
                }
            };
        }
```

**MVC Startup:**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie(setup => setup.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2))
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                    {
                        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                        options.ClientId = "Epp.Web.Mvc";
                        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                        options.ClientSecret = "secret";

                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                        options.SaveTokens = true;
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;


                        options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
                        options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
                        options.Scope.Add("epp");
                        options.Scope.Add("roles");
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            NameClaimType = "name",
                            RoleClaimType = "role"
                        };
                    });
```

Comment: don't actualize your tokens, revoke them and issue a new one

Comment: this is why role based authorization is avoided these days and scope based authorization is preferred with something like `service1.read, service2.full_access` scopes. You could either: move role based authorization into each service and away from identity server, convert to scope based authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the question is not specifically about OpenId-Connect, nor Identity server. It's more a generic question about how long to keep some cached (security) data. JWT is immutable by design, so you can treat it as a kind of cache. Once the cached item (or a jwt) expires, we get a new one. So the only solution is to set a reasonably short expiration for your bearer token and use a refresh one to "actualize" the bearer.

I personally can't see how changing roles to *scopes for a given service* can help. That's about a bit different thing. We can more or less constantly define that `application1` has access to `service1.write` scope, and by that restrict `All but application1' users` from access to the API. But what if the app is universal? No answer here.

Another suggestion was to use reference tokens and invalidate when necessary. Well, you could do. But by default the API caches the reference token validation' result, so... We get the same problem in a new place.

What should work is moving role based authorization into each service, as @VidmantasBlazevicius suggested, but again inside the service you most likely have some cache, so you again have to think how to invalidate it when necessary.

Comment: I would avoid mixing this topic with caching as his problem has nothing to do with caching. Unless all his microservices adhere and respect the same role context, this architecture is simply bound to fail regardless of what caching mechanism you have.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, my point is that jwt (in the context of the question) is just a kind of `cache item`. Issuing a fresh token is semantically the same as re-creating such an item.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I like solution with short lifetime access token but I have strange trouble with expire of access token. I repeated example from official repo [link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/IdentityServer) and set short  AccessTokenLifeTime = 60 and IdentityTokenLifeTime = 60. Then I authorize on my site and wait 2 minutes. I did reload page and check Access_Token using `await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` but it's old! What is wrong I do?

Comment: you request the token from your local httpContext, where you store it previously by setting `SaveTokens = true;` so that's the old good token, you are right : )

Comment: what you need to do is using corresponding `HttpClient` [extension method](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html) with the `refresh_token` you keep. that gives you a new pair of access and refresh tokens

Comment: with short ttl you may face one more issue: your expired tokens will be still accepted by clients 5 minutes after expiration -- so called clock skew. that has nothing to do with token issuing, only validation. and the setting [can be changed](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/issues/90)

Comment: @d_f Thanks, will try tomorrow this :) Как приеду в Питер, найду тебя и отблагодарю :))

Comment: @d_f Hello again:) I have new question with reference token. I tried use access token with short lifetime, it's works but i have explicit redirects in browser on client and want try reference token. But have issue with caching. Maybe you know about this and can help me in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573592/identityserver4-reference-token-caching-options) ? :)

Comment: @slav4ik51493, I took a couple days off. have you solved that one with VidmantasBlazevicius? if not, I can try to look into it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 way to do it as below,

1. You can user reference token flow and invalidate token when changes occurs in your role/rights. Check link http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html
2. Or as mentioned by @Vidmantas Blazevicius, move role based authorization job to respective service rather than relay on identity server.