# IdentityServer4 Reference Token caching options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, token, identityserver4

I use IdentityServer4 and want use it for mine microservices.
I have two services now: 
- AuthService 
- MVC site 
I want use reference token with short lifetime cycle for often requesting actual claims from AuthService, but I can't found property for setting cache lifetime.

How I can configure cache time for claims and is it good idea for getting actual claims for user?

I tried set AccessTokenLifeTime, IdentityTokenLifeTime, TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew, but it's not work for this task.

**MVC Startup:**

```
...
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                    options.ClientId = "client";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
                    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
                    options.Scope.Add("epp");
                    options.Scope.Add("roles");
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        RoleClaimType = "role",
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                    };
                });
...
```

**Auth Service, Config.cs:**

```
...
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client",
                    ClientName = "Display name",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = new List<string>{GrantType.Hybrid},
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "epp",
                        "roles",
                    },
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        "https://localhost:5003/signin-oidc"
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>{ "https://localhost:5003/signout-callback-oidc" },

                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 10,
                    IdentityTokenLifetime = 10,
                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true
                }
```

Comment: do you want the mvc site to cache the token?

Comment: I can't see anything related to [AccessTokenValidation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation) in your client side config. without it wouldn't work with reference token. that's pretty custom. once again, I would suggest to start with normal jwt + refresh token.

Comment: and you have to catch the difference between the `identity_token` and settings for that and `access_token`. the first one, more or less transformed, lives in your mvc for internal authentication. the second one is used for calling APIs, when protecting them with [JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no caching layer for claims. The claims along with the `ClaimsPrincipal` are rebuilt every time a protected (`[Authorize]`) endpoint is ran. This is done by the authentication middleware. Normally, you would have cookie authentication scheme which allows you to avoid going back to the UserInfo endpoint every time and in general the revalidation of the token until it expires or the authentication cookie is effectively removed (through sign out or other means).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But what is incorrect in my configuration? I send role claim on authorize, it's work correct on page with attribute `[Authorize(Role = 'Admin')]`, after this delete user from role, wait 20 seconds (lifetime of token equals 10 sec) and refresh page with authorize attribute. And it doesn't work. What I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work, none of this info you just said was included in the question.

Comment: @slav4ik51493 do you mean that the fact you deleted from role doesn't take effect?

Comment: yes, i mean after deleted from role doesn't take effect. Am I expecting what should not be? Or do I still have configuration problems?

Comment: It's because of `ClockSkew` then. Your token is still considered valid.

Comment: But I set ClockSkew = 10 seconds

Comment: Try adding `options.UseTokenLifetime = true;`